# Android: get past mobile data stats

Tags: java, android, mobile, statistics, wifi

I'm trying to obtain the data stats in Android (also WiFi) of a past period.
I know there is the [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class, but it seems to make available just the infos about the current connection.
I'd like to obtain something about: "Get the data received in the last month".
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing available for this in the Android SDK, unless you collect the data yourself via `TrafficStats`.